# Iptables blocking smtp

Tags: email, iptables, web-server, firewall, smtp

Iptables is blocking outgoing and incomming smtp on my server, although I specified it not to. My policies are DROP everything except what's specified. Changing policies to ACCEPT everything "solves" the problem, but I don't want unlimited traffic on this server. Rules were set as follows (smtp part is the last):

```
# Flush all rules
iptables -F
iptables -X

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming and outgoing SSH
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming HTTP/HTTPS
# HTTP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# HTTPS
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 443 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow outgoing SMTP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 25 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --sport 25 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Finally, change policy to DROP ALL
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

It's a webserver. [Django's `send_mail` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#send-mail) is what is being used to send mail. Settings are as follows:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'person@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

I assumed 587 was being used for email, so I added for port 587 the same rules shown above for port 25. I also tried switching `--dport`/`--sport` for smtp, nothing. Setting the rules as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670742/how-to-allow-mail-through-iptables) and [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/404581/sendmail-doesnt-work-with-iptables-even-though-smtp-and-dns-are-allowed) questions (both for port 25 and 587) didn't help either. I even tried doing the same for port 1025, just because it was mentioned on the docs, nothing...

Comment: Can you make sure that it works with iptables off? (Flush all tables.)

Comment: I am sure it works with all tables flushed (and policies changed to ACCEPT).

Comment: Did you look at the exception you received from your Django app?

Comment: I "fixed it" by using a (very) less restrictive [set of rules](http://pastebin.com/ZFVLJRDX). @MichaelHampton `gaierror at /contact/mailto [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your firewall rules do not allow DNS traffic (UDP port 53). Thus your Django app cannot perform a DNS lookup to locate `smtp.gmail.com`:

```
gaierror at /contact/mailto [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

To fix this, write firewall rules which permit outgoing DNS queries and incoming DNS responses.

Answer (score 0):

Can it be that  the --sport and --dsport should be the other way round ?

```
# Allow outgoing SMTP
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 587 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j A
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --sport 587 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```